# Create second property file from first property file using Maven

Tags: maven-3

I have s1.properties file in src/main/resources folder in project. It contents are

```
k1=v1
k2=v2
k3=v3
```

I have to create new file called t1.properties which shall have below mentioned contents

```
k1=@k1@
k2=@k2@
k3=@k3@
```

As you can see , my t1.properties file contents have been derived from s1.properties's keys. so, for all keys in s1.properties, I want to create t1.properties which above mentioned contents.

I hope I am able to understand my requirement.

I searched over internet but could not find a way to do through Maven.

Please let me know if it is possible to do it through Maven.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this requirement through custom java code and maven exec plugin